# return a data from ajax method returning status 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, bad-request

I have an ajax function that i want to return the value of it from my function. Its like a function calling an ajax function and waiting for return value.

Here is my function calculate:

```
function calculate() {                   
    let start_date = $('[name="date_start"]').val();
    let start_newdate = start_date.split("/").reverse().join("-");    
    let end_date = $('[name="date_end"]').val();
    let end_newdate = end_date.split("/").reverse().join("-");    
    let status = $('[name="salary_status"]').val();

    let data_check = check_calculate_if_exist(start_newdate,date_end);
    data_check.success(function (data) {
      alert(data);
    });
}
```

This is my ajax function that i want to return some value:

```
function check_calculate_if_exist(date_start,date_end) {
    return $.ajax({
        url : base_url+"hello/admin_check/check_data/"+date_start+"/"+date_end,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // this
        dataType: "json", // and this        
    });
}
```

executing this would return status code 400 bad request

Comment: Where is the `data` attribute apart from `url` `type` etc ?

Comment: @swapnesh i have no data to be passed just the parameters

Comment: @swapnesh i just added dataType json because i saw any answers in stackoverflow. but it seems it doesnt work in my case